# Set theme programatically to Android system preview window

Tags: android, android-theme

I have an app in which the user can choose between the default theme and a dark theme. The manifest applies `AppTheme` to the `<application>`, while each activity checks the relevant flag and uses `setTheme(AppTheme.Dark)` if necessary.

This implementation works well for all my activities, but the preview window shown by the OS *before* the application launches uses the Manifest theme, i.e. the light one. So users get a sudden white screen before reaching the dark app.

Based on other SO answers, I gathered that the only customization we can do is to set a `windowBackground` drawable for the window to use (and a `statusBarColor` if needed).

Even though I have two different `windowBackground` set for each theme, I can't change the theme for the preview window since the `Application` class seems to load after it, and setting theme there makes no difference.

I'd like to avoid disabling the preview since it adds a noticeable delay without much indication that the app is launching. Is there any solution to this?  I'm considering having a dark color for both themes in the worst case, like the Reddit app does.

**Styles:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- primary and accent color attributes -->

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/activityBackgroundLight</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="AppTheme">
    <!-- primary and accent color attributes -->

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/activityBackgroundDark</item>
</style>
```

Note: While I'm using colors here, I've already tried with a gradient drawable and it doesn't change anything.

---

**UPDATE:** I wasn't able to get any other method, so I went ahead and applied the dark theme by default on the SplashActivity. This means the preview window is always dark, while the check in the SplashActivity's `onCreate` is inverted (compared to other activities) and applies the light theme if needed.

Still looking for a solution that actually lets me switch at runtime.

Comment: I'm having the same problem right now. Did you end up finding anything?

Comment: I ended up doing what is mentioned in the "update" section at the end of the question. Not sure if anything has changed over the past year, since I didn't actively continue looking for a solution.